# Is it possible to know if an html5 video was played/paused via the play()/pause() javascript methods?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm trying to figure out if a video was played/paused via `play()` and `pause()` javascript methods.

I thought I could achieve this by observing the 'play' and 'pause' events checking if `isTrusted` was **false**. Up to no avail, this always comes **true**.

Is there any way for me to know if a video was played or paused due to an user interaction?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3x2rhdf/)

__

extra:
I have even tried `videoElement.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))` but this doesn't seem to trigger the play/pause events of the video

Comment: In one hand you ask to know if the video was played using the HTMLMediaElement methods, then you ask if it was played from user interaction. Both are different but not contradictory, and user interaction could lead to these methods being called.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there are two separate things you can observer here:

- changes in video state
- user interactions, via mouse clicks etc
- user interactions via the keyboard using the 'onkeydown' (replaces the deprecated 'keypress' event)

You may want to monitor and relate all for completeness but the simplest way would seem to be to simply monitor clicks of the UI Play/Pause button itself.

If you are able to use a HTML5 video player for your solution rather than the 'raw' view tag, you can leverage it's event handling for the UI which may be more convenient. For example for VideoJS you have the ClickableComponent (https://docs.videojs.com/clickablecomponent#handleKeyDown):

> handleKeyDown(event).  button.js, line 107
>
> This gets called when a Button has focus and keydown is triggered via a key press.

Comment: i understand that. There are other ways for a user to play/pause a video that would be missed out if we are looking for the button clicks. Like a multimedia keyboard key press, or some hotkey to play/pause like spacebar. I think this does work, but I wanted something less prone to fail. It just seems to me that the play/pause event should have isTrusted set to false, as if it is a bug.

Comment: Yes, you can also monitor those - added a note, but I think your point is that you should not have to and should be able to look at the information shared in the media pause and play events - I think you are correct that this is not the case at this time anyway.